# DSN_MAILER with the host 02switch

Tags: symfony, host, mailer

Good morning all,

I would like to deploy an update on my site allowing me to send emails, I used Mailer. I am under symfony 4.4 My host is 02switch. How do I configure my MAILER_DSN in my .env? Locally I am like this: MAILER_DSN = smtp: // localhost: 1025

I sent them an email but they don't seem to know.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The format is as follows:

MAILER_DSN=smtp://user:pass@smtp.example.com:25

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not know what to put which password?
I was told to put this but I have an error:MAILER_DSN=smtp:lettonie.o2switch.net.o2switch.net:465

Comment: I found:MAILER_DSN=smtp:lettonie.o2switch.net:465